# SQL query and execution plan in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, jdbc

I am new to the SQL Server and we are using 10.0.x version. It is a 7/8 years old java/j2ee application with the latest version of JDBC drivers. The application is using more than a hundred SELECT queries with PreparedStatement.

Our DBA argues that since these queries are coming from an external application, for each query SQL server creates an execution plan and it makes the database very slow. He is saying we need to create more than a hundred stored procedures (for each query) and use those stored procs in java application. When java application goes through the stored procedure, SQL server caches execution plan, so it will be efficient. I know it is NOT correct.

If someone knows, could you please send some SQL server documentation that SQL Server caches these statements for java preparedStatement? Or some pointers.

Thanks,
Raj

Comment: You can find a good explanation and example for what you are searching in SQL Server: https://sqlperformance.com/2018/07/performance-myths/query-result-cache

Comment: @OlivierBelanger  Follow up question on the same. So execution plan gets executed for every query doesn't matter it is from stored proc or JDBC query. Right?

Comment: That's absolutely right, it doesn't really matter. Logically, you are not running 50 query at the same time, so you should'nt be suppose to have a lot of slow performance. Hope it helps

Comment: @OlivierBelanger Just want to make sure even in the multi-tenant environment, execution plan gets executed for every query. Just want to confirm.

Thanks.